# Duplicate keys in dictionary from database

Tags: python, sqlite

when i make a query to my database, i return the values as such:

```
tuplematches = cursor.fetchall()
for items in tuplematches:
    print(items)
```

prints as:

```
    NAME/                     PRICE/  HOURS/
1. ('honda accord 2nd light', 20.00, 10.0)
2. ('honda accord 2nd light', 22.00, 17.0)
3. ('chevy silverado headlight', 30.00, 20.0)
```

what i want is to create a dictionary where the key is the name of the item, 
and the value is a list that includes the totalsum of all prices for the item with this name, as well as the sum of the hours, and number of times NAME has occurred. for each individual name:

```
    mydict[name] = [summed price, summed hours, occurences]
    mydict['honda accord 2nd light'] = [42.00, 27.0, 2]
```

ive tried several different ways, but i cant figure out why, instead of giving me nonduplicate names as keys with its all of it's combined values, it gives me a dictionary with multiple different instances of the same name and their own different values, which does me no good. like this:

```
    mydict['honda accord 2nd light'] = [21.00, 13.5, 2]
    mydict['honda accord 2nd light'] = [44.00, 27.0, 2]
    mydict['honda accord 2nd light'] = [23.00, 19.0, 5]
```

the ultimate goal here is to get the average prices, averages hours, and total occurences for each itemname.

```
    dict[name] = [average price,  average hours, total occurences]
```

any idea what i can do to make this easier and a little less painful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with database already, why not do the aggregation within the query?

```
select NAME, SUM(PRICE) AS PRICE, SUM(HOURS) AS HOURS, COUNT(*) AS OCCURENCE
from ...
group by NAME
```

Comment: im very inexperienced with sqlite3, so im gonna have to practice this to make sure i do it right before i can tell you if it works for me, lol. thanks!

Comment: perfect! this was exactly what i was looking for!